# Rails: Ajax: Changes Onload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, onload

I have a web layout of a for that looks something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="posts">
      <div id="post1" class="post" >
         <!--stuff 1-->
      </div>
      <div id="post2" class="post" >
         <!--stuff 1-->
      </div>

      <!-- 96 more posts -->

      <div id="post99" class="post" >
         <!--stuff 1-->
      </div>
    </div>          

  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to load and render the page with a blank , and then have a function called when the page is loaded which goes in and load up the posts and updates the page dynamically.

In Rails, I tried using "link_to_remote" to update  with all of the  elements. I also tweaked the posts controller to render the collection of posts if it was an ajax request (request.xhr?).   It worked fine and very fast. However the update of the blank div is triggered by clicking the link. I would like the same action to happen when the page is loaded so that I don't have to put in a link.

**Is there a Rails Ajax helper or RJS function or something in Rails that I could use to trigger the loading of the "posts" after the page has loaded and rendered (without the posts)?**

(If putsch comes to shove, I will just copy the generated JS code from the link_to_remote call and have it called from the onload handler on the body).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there is, it's Rails, after all :)

Something like that will do:

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <%= remote_function(:update => "posts", :url => posts_partial_path) %>
  });
<% end %>
```

remote_function will give you the same javascript that gets executed when you use rails ajax helpers.

Comment: Thanks. I used something like this, except that I used jQuery to do it unobtrusively.

Comment: @jay please can you answer the question of butterwombat

Answer (score 1):

Do this using jQuery unobtrusively like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({url: 'posts_partial_path',
           success: function(data) {
             $('#posts').html(data);
           }
  });
});
```

putting this code in a JavaScript file included by your page. You need to replace 'posts_partial_path' above with the actual URL string, Rails helpers are not available in the JavaScript code. Read about making AJAX calls with jQuery here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . Works like a champ.

Walter Gillett